# Pass function member pointer as parameter to function

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I'm working on a Qt project and I have decided to implement a function which takes a pointer to a `QLabel` member function and its parameters, and applies it to some labels.

```
template <class R, class ...Args>
void ClockSim::applyToLabels (R (QLabel::*f)(Args...), Args&& ...args)
{
    ui->labelSingleTime->*f (std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    //Repeat it for many other labels

}
```

I tried to call it with:

```
applyToLabels (&QLabel::setStyleSheet, "color:red;");
```

It says:

error: *no matching member function for call to 'applyToLabels'*

*candidate template ignored: could not match 'QLabel' against 'QWidget'*

Any solution? Thanks

Comment: Why is it saying `QWidget ` in the error ?You are not showing the complete example ?

Comment: ClockSim is a derived class of QWidget, nothing else.

Comment: Also you are passing an argument of type `char const (&)[10]`. If your member function expects `const char*`, the this would not work (probably there would be some ambiguity)

Comment: Well `QLabel::setStyleSheet` expects a `QString&`, but even if i use `QString {"color:red;"}` the error remains the same.

Comment: Also do not forget you need to pass an instance of the class as well if it is a non static member function.

Comment: @MattiaF. That wont work if QString is anything like std::string

Comment: @MattiaF. `"color:red;" is a temporary string literal, you can't pass that to a function expecting a non const reference

Comment: Is `setStylesSheet` just a typo for `setStyleSheet`?  If so, please [edit] your question to fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `setStylesSheet` is an inherited member of `QWidget`, the type of `&QLabel::setStylesSheet` is actually `void (QWidget::*)(const QString&)`, and that doesn't match your template function parameter.

You'll need to use another template parameter for the actual class of the member function:

```
template <class R, class C, class ...Params, class ...Args>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<C,QLabel>::value &&
                        sizeof...(Params)==sizeof...(Args)>::type 
ClockSim::applyToLabels (R (C::*f)(Params...), Args&& ...args)
{
    (ui->labelSingleTime->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I've also made the function pointer parameters different from your passed args, since you try to pass a `const char(&)[11]` which is not a `QString` but converts to one.

Comment: Nice, I was going to post answer but it looks similar as mine: here is some test source code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d64862509212d127

Comment: Aren't base class member function pointers implicitly convertible to derived class member function pointers?

Comment: @John: Yes, but that doesn't mean template type deduction can deal with the possible conversion.